# InvalidRequestError: This customer has no attached payment source

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I've been following the Quickstart guides from Stripe.

https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart

https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart

This is what my form looks like:

```
<form id="register-form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in registration_form %}
        <p>{{ field }}</p>
        {% if field.errors %}
            <p class="text-danger">{{ field.errors.as_text|cut:"* "|escape }}</p>
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
    {% if registration_form.non_field_errors %}
        <p class="text-danger">{{ registration_form.non_field_errors.as_text|cut:"* "|escape }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    <div id="stripe-wrapper">
        <p id="card-element"></p>
    </div>                  
    <p id="card-errors" role="alert"></p>
    <button id="register-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var displayError=   document.getElementById('card-errors');
        var stripe=         Stripe("pk_test_BjhejGz5DZNcSHUVaqoipMtF");
        var elements=       stripe.elements();

        var style=      {
            base: {
                fontSize: "1.1875rem",
                fontSmoothing: "always",
                fontWeight: "600"
            }
        };

        var card=   elements.create("card",{style:style});
        card.mount("#card-element");
        card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {

            if (event.error) {
                displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
            } else {
                displayError.textContent = '';
            }
        });

        var formID= "register-form";
        var form=   document.getElementById(formID);
        form.addEventListener("submit",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result){
                if(result.error) {
                    displayError.textContent=   result.error.message;
                } else {
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token, formID);
                }                               
            })
        });
        // tut https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart#create-form
        function stripeTokenHandler(token, formID) {
            // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
            var form = document.getElementById(formID);
            var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
            form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
            // Submit the form
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Then my `views.py` has this:

```
if registration_form.is_valid():
    stripe.api_key= "sk_test_8rdFokhVsbsJJysHeKgyrMTc"
    stripeCustomer= stripe.Customer.create(
        email=request.POST["username"],
    )
    subscription=   stripe.Subscription.create(
        customer=stripeCustomer["id"],
        items=[{"plan":"plan_CLFfBrRAKl7TRt"}],
    )
```

This gives me an error:

```
Internal Server Error: /login-register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/pages/middleware.py", line 98, in process_view
    return view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/product_blog/theme/views.py", line 154, in login_register
    items=[{"plan":"plan_CLFfBrRAKl7TRt"}],
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/subscription.py", line 33, in create
    return super(Subscription, cls).create(**params)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py", line 17, in create
    response, api_key = requestor.request('post', url, params, headers)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 153, in request
    resp = self.interpret_response(rbody, rcode, rheaders)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 365, in interpret_response
    self.handle_error_response(rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders)
  File "/home/myUserName/myDjangoProjectWithStripe/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stripe/api_requestor.py", line 178, in handle_error_response
    raise err
InvalidRequestError: Request req_o39ceLlhtpJmmr: This customer has no attached payment source
```

How do I attach a payment source to the customer? Since I'm testing, I use the testing credit card, which has the number `4242 4242 4242 4242`.

Comment: The issue is that you can't create a Subscription in Stripe if the Customer doesn't have a card (payment source) registered.

Comment: @Rasovica How do I attach the payment source to the Customer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error means what it says, the customer doesn't have an attached payment method/source. You are adding a `stripeToken` to your html form, but you aren't doing anything with it server side. You need to add the token to your customer (set `source` to the token when creating the customer) and then you'll be able to charge the customer, create subscriptions, etc.

Comment: Do I put `source` attribute in the `Customer` or `Subscription` object?

Comment: On Customer, because Subscription require the payment to be configured before a customer is subscribed to a plan. An update to this question in 2020 is that source is [outdated](https://stripe.com/docs/sources), now you can use [payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add payment form to your registration,
Assuming you have a /payment-form route, in your views.py add the following:

```
from yourapp import settings

def payment_form(request):
    context = { "stripe_key": settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }
    return render(request, "yourtemplate.html", context)
```

In your template, copy and paste the form found under the checkout section of the stripe docs.

```
<form action="/checkout" method="POST">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="stripe_key" # Make sure to wrap the variable name with double {}
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Your APp"
    data-description="Your Product"
    data-image="Link to your logo"
    data-currency="usd">
</script>
</form>
```

Notice we passed the stripe public_key to the data-key attribute, by default, it will be populated with your actual public key, but I just find it better to use the variable instead.

We also set the action attribute of the form to /checkout which we’ll create in the next step. This route will process the checkout logic.

What’s actually happening is this: When a user submits the form (ie: pays), their bank account information is sent to stripe for processing. If the payment is accepted, stripe will issue a POST request to the endpoint specified in the action attribute of the form. The idea is to then capture that token and use it to charge the user’s card.

Comment: In my case, I'm not using a Stripe button to submit the info. I'll update my question with the HTML